# Lipschitz type estimate for the Green function for fractional Laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let  $G(x, y)$ be the Green function of the  fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^s$ in a bounded interval $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with $G(x, y)=0$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus I$ and $s\in (0, 1).$ Is it possible to obtain an estimate of the form
$|G(x, y)- G(x, z)|\leq C|y-z|$ where $C>0$ might depend on $x.$

Answer (score 2):

No: the estimate fails when $y, z$ are close to each other and also close to either $x$ or one of the endpoints of $I$.

Observe that we have $$G(x, y) = C(s) |x - y|^{2 s - 1} + h(x, y) ,$$ where $C(s)$ is some constant and $h(x, y)$ is a smooth function in the interior of $I$ (for $h(x, \cdot)$ is the $(-\Delta)^s$-harmonic reduction of $C(s) |x - \cdot|^{2 s - 1}$ in $I$). Thus your estimate cannot hold when $y, z \approx x$. (The case $s = \tfrac{1}{2}$ is different, you have $\log |x - y|$ instead of $|x - y|^{2 s - 1}$).

Similarly, it is known that $G(x, y) \sim \tilde{C}(s) (\operatorname{dist}(y, \partial I))^{s/2}$ as $y$ converges to one of the endpoints of $I$, so $G(x, \cdot)$ is not Lipshitz continuous there.

By the way, $G(x, y)$ is known explicitly (in terms of $_2F_1$ or in an integral form), the expression was given by M. Riesz, Kac and Blumenthal–Getoor–Ray. Any standard reference on the fractional Laplacian and its potential theory (e.g. Landkoff, Bliedtner–Hansen) discusses these subjects.